# Install application in sd card by default using Linux

Tags: applications, rooting, sd-card, installation

I've seen plenty of tutorials related to installing applications directly to the sd card instead of using internal memory but none relate to using linux as a method to tweak the system and I'm not managing to understand it by myself. I have android studio installed and consequently the sdk and development tools aswell as my device is in developer mode but I'd like to understand what I should do next to directly install into the sd card.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. You don't need a Linux-specific tutorial: the dev tools work exactly the same way on all three desktop OSes.

Answer (score 1):

It is as simple as running `adb install -s someapp.apk`. However, the app should be ready to run from external storage.

`adb` resides in the `path to ADT/sdk/platform-tools` directory.

Related question: [Move to SD Card doesn't move everything](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/12723/54885)